# Finding current layer name in QGIS field calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, layers, fields-attributes, layer-name

How do I find the current layer name in the QGIS field calculator ?

My goal is to mass process multiple layers and retrieve codes written in their names.

I've find the "base_name_file" function but it needs to be manually feed with the layer name where I hope to automatically use the layer's name which is processed.

Comment: @layer_name? ..,-

Comment: I feel like an idiot... Thank you MrXsquared !